# Can you help me get this PHP explode/array/numrows/etc block working?

Tags: php, for-loop

Ok, so here's my code:

```
if ($_GET['send'] === "yes") {
    $name = $_POST['msg-to'].", ";
    $nameParts = explode(", ", $name);
    $recipients = array();
    for ($x = 0; $x >= 10; $x++) {
        $name_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$nameParts[$x]."'");
        while($value = mysql_fetch_array($name_query)){ $name_numrows = mysql_num_rows($name_query); }
        if ($name_numrows = 1) {
            $recipients[$x] = $nameParts[$x];
            $msgError .= '<span class="success">'.$nameParts[$x].' is a valid user.</span><br>';
        } else {
            $msgError .= '<span class="warning">'.$nameParts[$x].' is not a valid user, message did not send.</span><br>';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But when a user enters a username for this message to be sent to, it doesn't seem to work AT ALL. It doesn't echo either of the two error messages, and doesn't return an error. It doesn't do anything.

Any feedback at all would be absolutely wonderful :D

Comment: `for ($x = 0; $x >= 10; $x++) {` This will never work...

Comment: Ok, I fixed it to `for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to help in the comments above but I think a more clear explanation is needed so I'm resorting to posting an answers. Your code:

```
for ($x = 0; $x >= 10; $x++) {
```

This code block declares `$x = 0` as the first part of the statement, this is the initialisation.

The second part `$x >= 10` is the condition. It states that while `$x` is **greater than or equal to** `10` you want to execute an iteration of the loop.

The final part `$x++` is the afterthought. It states that on each successful iteration of the loop you want to increment the value of `$x`.

Because you initialise `$x` to be `0` and then set the condition that it has to be **greater than or equal to** 10 `>= 10` the condition will fail first time, every time. 0 can't be great than or equal to 10. I imagine what you probably want for your condition is something like while `$x` is **less than or equal to 10** `$x <= 10`.